# What is the meaning of "font" in this code?

Tags: c

```
#ifndef objptr
  typedef struct { int kind; } gui_obj;
  typedef gui_obj * objptr;
#endif

typedef objptr font;          /* font of certain size and style */
font a;
```

Is the "a" an integer or a pointer to integer?

```
  typedef gui_obj * objptr;
```

What does this sentence mean ?

Comment: After `typedef gui_obj * objptr;` and `typedef objptr font;`, then `font a;` is the same as `gui_obj *a;`. The variable `a` is a pointer to a *structure*, whose only member is an `int` value named `kind`. You can do e.g. `a.kind = 5;` elsewhere in the code. The `typedef` keyword is used to introduce an alias for a type. Any decent book, tutorial or class should have the information needed.

Comment: @gesanghuakai ya - please consider upvoting and/or accepting one or more of the answers  below.

Answer (score 1):

Translate the code into English and you'll understand what the code does (means).

```
// if the macro (constant) 'objptr' is not defined
#ifndef objptr

  // define a new type named 'gui_obj',
  // which is a struct that contains one
  // member named 'kind' of type 'int'
  typedef struct { int kind; } gui_obj;

  // define a new type named 'objptr',
  // which type is a pointer to a type named 'gui_obj',
  // which means that variables of type 'objptr' will be able
  // to store the addresses to types of 'struct gui_obj'
  typedef gui_obj * objptr;

#endif

// define a new type named 'font',
// which is a type of 'objptr'
typedef objptr font;

// declare a variable named 'a' of type 'font'
font a;
```

So, in short `font` is a type alias to `objptr`, which is a type alias to `gui_obj*`, and `gui_obj` is a type alias to `struct gui_obj`.  So `font` is an alias for `struct gui_obj*`.

Usage of `a`, e.g.

```
a->kind = 42;
// or
(*a).kind = 42;
// in english:
// dereference the object 'a', 
// which is of type 'font',
// which is an alias of 'objptr'
// which is an alias of pointer to 'gui_obj',
// which is a struct, 
// that contains a member named 'kind' of type 'int',
// that can be accessed and set to e.g. '42'
```

**OT:** the problem with the above example is, that if `objptr` was already defined and is something completely different than the `struct gui_obj`, e.g. does not have a member `kind` or is some scalar type.

Comment: Excellent reply.  ALSO:  `#ifndef OBJPTR` (upper case for macros) would have been a *MUCH* better choice than "#ifndef objptr".  Using "OBJPTR" adheres to "C" naming conventions ... and avoids conflating the preprocessor macro with the compile-time "type".

Comment: @paulsm4 <Using "OBJPTR" adheres to "C" naming conventions> --> that is a common though not specified style issue not even fully followed by the C spec.

Answer (score 0):

First, 'a' is a struct pointer which can point to a struct gui_obj. A struct gui_obj has an integer member: kind. If 'a' does point to a struct gui_obj, you can get its member by this sentence
`a->kind`.

Second, `typedef gui_obj * objptr;` means you define a new type whose name is objptr, and it's equivalent to `gui_obj *`, struct pointer.

Answer (score 0):

> What is the meaning of "font" in this code?

`typedef objptr font;` defines a new type name called `font`.  It is the same type as `objptr`.

> Is the "a" an integer or a pointer to integer?

It is neither.  `a` is a pointer to `gui_obj`.  `gui_obj` is a structure.

> What does this sentence mean ?

`typedef gui_obj * objptr;` defines a new type called `objptr`.  It is a pointer to `gui_obj`.